# Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying to resolve nugget packages with `dotnet restore`, but am getting the following error:

> Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'

Here's my `.csproj` file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extras.Moq" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Core" Version="1.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Easy.MessageHub" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="hangfire" Version="1.6.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MemoryStorage" Version="1.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.0-rc1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="ApplyXdtConfigTransform" BeforeTargets="_TransformWebConfig">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_SourceWebConfig>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Web.config</_SourceWebConfig>
      <_XdtTransform>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Web.$(Configuration).config</_XdtTransform>
      <_TargetWebConfig>$(PublishDir)Web.config</_TargetWebConfig>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="dotnet transform-xdt --xml &quot;$(_SourceWebConfig)&quot; --transform &quot;$(_XdtTransform)&quot; --output &quot;$(_TargetWebConfig)&quot;" Condition="Exists('$(_XdtTransform)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I have installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-rc1-008673-win-x64 and I am using Visual Studio 2017 v15.2

Answer (score 8):

Update your `nuget.config` file located in:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
```

You need to add the `v3` endpoint like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />   
    </packageSources>
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a long time. Thanks for the answer that solved by problem. Are there any other variations for this? Where is the documentation for this configuration?

Comment: I am not sure why the file `NuGet.config` was empty when I did the setup on my work laptop, but it was configured properly on my personal laptop. I really wanted to know how this file gets created and under which process? Is it part of the MSBuild Tool Install or part of the NuGet vscode extension install?

Answer (score 5):

You can add the v3 nuget source via the dotnet cli:

```sh
dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

If that doesn't work, try running clearing out the local cache:

```sh
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
dotnet restore --force
```

#### Further Reading

- [Unable to resolve .NETCoreApp v3.1 Packages](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21920)
- [Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 3.0.0)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58787682/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was Visual Studio version.

Solution was to create MSBuildSdksPath environment variable that is pointing to dotnet\sdk{{version}}\Sdks, like on the following link https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/231

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my project in .net core 3.1.0 Following are the steps

> dotnet nuget locals all --clear
> dotnet restore --force