# Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, package, blazor

Good day,

I am trying to add a package named 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 3.0.0' in my ASP.NET Core Blazor application in VS Code. But I am getting the following error.

P.s. This is my first time working with VS Code.

**Terminal**

```
g:\Workspace\Test>dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 3.0.0
  Writing C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDB70.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' into project 'g:\Workspace\Test\Test.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for g:\Workspace\Test\Test.csproj...
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 3.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
error: Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'g:\Workspace\Test\Test.csproj'.
```

**.NET Info**

```
g:\Workspace\Test>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  95a0a61858

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

A couple of posts suggested that I **clear Nuget cache** which I did. But still in vain.

```
 g:\Workspace\Test>dotnet nuget locals all --clear
    info : Clearing NuGet HTTP cache: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
    info : Clearing NuGet global packages folder: C:\Users\dell\.nuget\packages\
    info : Clearing NuGet Temp cache: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
    info : Clearing NuGet plugins cache: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache
    info : Local resources cleared.

    g:\Workspace\Test>dotnet restore --force
      Restore completed in 50.68 ms for g:\Workspace\Test\Test.csproj.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, that should have worked. Altough I don't think you can specify `--version` like that.

Comment: Just tried this, and _it works on my machine_(TM)

By the looks of it, you are trying this on a clean machine with **only** .net core 3.0 installed. My best guess would be that somewhere down the dependency tree of the package (which is a lot) there is a dependency on the 2.2 of dotnet core or something. 

Could you try installing the dotnet core 2.2 runtime?

Comment: Just tried the same thing here: no problem (but I also have many previous SDKs installed). Is it possible you configured a different NuGet source somewhere?

Comment: I solved the issue by following the instructions given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798770/6181928

Comment: Try adding package with out specifying the `version`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Visual studio IDE, try to delete/cut the nuget config file somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Saswat M, welcome.. please look at the comments, before clicking "Answer". The issue was solved six months ago, by Junaid.