# Configure vs code for Selenium 4 - error while installing dotnet 6 sdk using PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, selenium, visual-studio-code

I was following the steps here:

https://www.fleekitsolutions.com/use-selenium-c-visual-studio-code/

To use Selenium 4 with vs code. Then this led me to the following instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60#install-with-powershell-automation

to install .NET 6 SDK using PowerShell script, and I got the error below:

> dotnet-install.ps1: Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3"
> argument(s): "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported
> compression method.

See the snapshot below.

My intention was to get the latest version of "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio" which led me to the above instructions to install dotnet 6 sdk.

Note the I am using elevated admin PowerShell console for this purpose.

I also got a similar error when I was trying to install the latest version of Selenium PowerShell Module using PowerShell. When I installed version 3.0.1 of Selenium-PowerShell module, it was successful.

Edit:
After installing .NET SDK 6 from MS Build Tools, I completed the steps to configure vscode for Selenium 4, and now I am getting this error:

```
PS> dotnet restore
```

> C:\Projects\Selenium\demoProject\FirstTest\FirstTest.csproj : error
> NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Selenium.WebDriver (>= 4.1.0)' for
> 'net6.0'.

Other things I tried:

I tried the following config in .csproj and nothing worked:

`<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>`
`<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`
`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Note that the sample Hello World Program of `dotnet new console` is working fine with all the TargetFramework I used above. The error occurs when I add Selenium.WebDriver to the project using NuGet package manager extension.

After I add the Selenium WebDriver, I get popup requesting to restore, and OmniSharp server will restart, and then a similar error shows up in the output:

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Projects\Selenium\demoProject\FirsProj\FirsProj.csproj'.
c:\Projects\Selenium\demoProject\FirsProj\FirsProj.csproj
c:\Projects\Selenium\demoProject\FirsProj\FirsProj.csproj(0,0): Error: Unable to resolve 'Selenium.WebDriver (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'.
c:\Projects\Selenium\demoProject\FirsProj\FirsProj.csproj(0,0): Error: Unable to resolve 'Selenium.WebDriver (>= 4.1.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8/win7-x86'.

[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: FirsProj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.PackageDependencyChecker
        FirsProj: Did not find 'Selenium.WebDriver' in lock file.
```

I appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems with the following:

1. Using MS Build Tools, I downloaded the needed .NET SDKs. I selected only the needed items. I didn't download Visual Studio.
2. I did try to download using older version such as using Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 but not sure exactly since I was trying a ton of steps...
3. There is an issue that the config section of NuGet is empty. Add the following part to `%appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />   
  </packageSources>
...
```

See this [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827282/4180447).

And, the error disappeared with both .NET 5 and .NET 6.

This is unfair, why it was so hard to find the solution?